# What's the most elegant way to create this series of numbers?

Tags: math, collections, language-agnostic, series, code-formatting

I have N items in a collection and I am assigning values starting from 1, going down to 0 in the "center" of the list, and then going back up to 1 linearly.

So if you have 5 items:

```
0   1   2   3   4
1   0.5 0   0.5 1
```

For 6 items, 2 items in the center would have the same value 0.

```
0   1   2   3   4   5
1   0.5 0   0   0.5 1
```

Right now I have a bunch of if statements checking for `index` and then deciding whether the value should go up or down from 1. But it seems too messy.

Is there an elegant way to create such a series of numbers (particularly without if statements if possible)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `N >= 3` is odd, then

```
f(x) = fabs(2*x-N+1)/(N-1)
```

If `N >= 4` is even, then

```
f(x) = (fabs(2*x-N+1) - 1)/(N-2)
```

To get totally rid of if-statements, you can write this as

```
f(x) = (fabs(2*x-N+1) + (N%2) - 1)/(N-2 + (N%2))
```

which works for even and odd values of `N >= 3`.